# Position in relative to parent view with auto layout in Objective C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, storyboard

I have a UITextView that I want always to be 10px from the bottom of it's parent view (the scrollview). Problem is that I don't know how to tell the auto layout that it is supposed to do Bottom Space To: Parentview, instead of superview.

This is what I have now:

[image]

**Update:**

I need something similar to this:

[image]

I got that from here - http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Working_with_iOS_6_Auto_Layout_Constraints_in_Interface_Builder - I want to have a UITextView in relation to the view it is in.

Comment: The "parent view" (the view that the UITextView is in) *is* its superview.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Click the gear for the “Bottom space to: superview” constraint and edit it.  Set the constant to 10.

#### UPDATE

I've investigated this a bit and decided there's a bug in autolayout.  Specifically, autolayout acts as if the size of the scroll view is 0⨉0 instead of its actual size.

Because of tis, if your text view has top-space-to-superview constraint and a bottom-space-to-superview constraint, only the top constraint will be honored.  (I tried setting the priority of the top constraint to 1, the minimum, and the bottom constraint was still ignored.)  If you delete the top constraint in `viewDidLoad`, the bottom constraint will be honored, but *the text view will be laid out as if the scroll view's height is zero*.  This means that the text view's bottom edge will be 10 points above the *top* edge of the scroll view.

This happens in my testing with both a storyboard and a xib.

Comment: Hmm ok. I'll try. How exactly should that help?

Comment: Doesn't work. It's sets it in relation to the superview. That's what I DON'T want. I want to set it in relation to the view it's in.

Comment: @HolgerEdwardWardlowSindbæk You need to explain what you mean by “the view it's in”, because every other iOS programmer (including me) thinks “the view it's in” means its superview.

Comment: It's inside a UIScrollView. So I want it to be 10 pixels from the bottom of the UIScrollView, not the superview. Sorry for being unclear.

Comment: Do you want the text view to move when the scroll view is scrolled?  Or do you want the text view to keep a fixed position on the screen?

Comment: Fixed at the bottom of the scrollview. It's inside the scrollview and should stay at the bottom of the scrollview.

Comment: You need to be more clear.  “Bottom of the scrollview” is ambiguous.  The scrollview has a bottom of its content area (defined by its `contentSize`) and a bottom of its frame.  so answer my question: Should the text view move when the scroll view scrolls?

Comment: Yes. It should move with the scrollview. It should be a subview of the scrollview and therefore also move when the user scrolls the scrollview. Thank you so much for getting me to be so precise.

Comment: Thanks a lot for testing this out for me. Seems weird to me that you can't apply these styles to subviews though. Should be something you should be able to do in iOS ya?! Anyway, I've accepted your answer.

Comment: And I managed to do it programatically instead. It's a bit clunky, but it works.